# Add BlackBerry Map to application

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-maps

I am trying to invoke the map application. I get an exception that says:

> MapException(error retrieving dictionaries).

Does my device need an active BlackBerry account to work with BlackBerry maps?

Comment: blackberry map is installed on your device ?

Comment: yes, its seems that. but i don't find the icon.

Comment: first check whether map is installed or not.

Comment: How i can find if is installed?

Comment: check whether the cod module is available or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int mh1 = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("net_rim_bb_lbs"); // For OS 4.5 - 5.0
int mh2 = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("net_rim_bb_maps"); // For OS 6.0

if (mh1 == 0 && mh2 == 0) {
       Dialog.alert("BlackBerry Maps not installed");
 }
```